# How do I submit a form from within an ajax callback inside a submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an AJAX form post within a submit function. If the success callback fires I want to submit the form. The way I have this now, the form does submit, but, of course, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. How do I exit the submit function properly so the form only submits once?

```
$(function() {
    var ccform = $('#ccForm'),
        ccnumber = $('#number'),
        ccexpiry = $('#expiry'),
        cartForm = $("#ShoppingCart");

    // If Qty Avail Exceeded is True Hide CC Payment Option and Form
    if ($('#qtyAvailExceeded').val() === "True") {
        //$('#ccOpt, #ccForm').hide();
    }

    // If Credit Card Payment Method Selected Show CC Form
    $('#paymethod').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'CCOpt') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                ccnumber.focus();
            }, 0);

            // Show CC Fields if CC option selected as payment method
            ccform.removeClass('hide');

            // Post CC to Paymentvalidate
            cartForm.submit(function(e) {

                var form = $(this),
                    action = $('#Action');

                action.val('PAYMENTVALIDATE');

                // Post Form if it validates
                if (form.parsley().isValid()) {
                    var pay = $.ajax({
                        url: "webcatpageserver.exe",
                        method: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            Action: $('#Action').val(),
                            Ship_Via: $('#shipVia').val(),
                            OrderMode: $('#orderMode').val(),
                            Order_Notes: $('#orderNotes').val(),
                            amountpaid: $('#amtPaid').val(),
                            cardnum: $('#cardNum').val(),
                            expiry: $('#expiry').val(),
                            cvc: $('#cvv').val(),
                            cardholder: $('#name').val()
                        },
                        cache: false
                    });
                    pay.done(function(data) {
                        if (data.DidValidate === false) {
                            ccAlert.html(data.ErrorMessage);
                            ccAlert.removeClass('hide');
                        } else if (data.DidValidate === true) {
                            ccAlert.html(data.ErrorMessage).addClass('hide');
                            action.val('SendOrderVerify');
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    });
                    pay.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            ccform.addClass('hide');
        }

        e.preventDefault();

    });

    // If CC Option Unavailable, Default to the Account Payment Option
    if ($('#ccOpt').length === 0) {
        $('#paymethod').val("AcctOpt");
    }

    // Initialize CC Form
    $('#ccForm').card({
        container: '.card-wrapper',
        width: 360,
        formSelectors: {
            numberInput: 'input#number',
            expiryInput: 'input#expiry',
            cvcInput: 'input#cvv',
            nameInput: 'input#name'
        }
    });

    // Check CC Card Type
    ccnumber.keyup(function() {
        var cvv = $('#cvv');
        if ($('.jp-card').hasClass('jp-card-amex')) {
            cvv.attr({
                'data-parsley-minlength': 4,
                'data-parsley-maxlength': 4
            });
        } else {
            cvv.attr({
                'data-parsley-minlength': 3,
                'data-parsley-maxlength': 3
            });
        }
    });

    // Remove Spaces from Card Number Before Submit to Paymentvalidate
    ccnumber.on('change', function() {
        var ccnumberNoSpaces = $('#number').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
        $('#cardNum').val(ccnumberNoSpaces);
    });
});
```

**CONSOLIDATED UPDATE - NOT WORKING**

```
$(function() {
    var ccform = $('#ccForm'),
        ccnumber = $('#number'),
        ccexpiry = $('#expiry'),
        cartForm = $("#ShoppingCart");

    cartForm.submit(function(e) {

        var form = $(this),
            action = $('#Action'),
            ccAlert = $('#ccAlert');

        if (action.val() != 'SendOrderVerify') {

            e.preventDefault();

            // Post Form if it validates
            if (form.parsley().isValid()) {
                action.val('PAYMENTVALIDATE');
                var pay = $.ajax({
                    url: "webcatpageserver.exe",
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        Action: $('#Action').val(),
                        Ship_Via: $('#shipVia').val(),
                        OrderMode: $('#orderMode').val(),
                        Order_Notes: $('#orderNotes').val(),
                        amountpaid: $('#amtPaid').val(),
                        cardnum: $('#cardNum').val(),
                        expiry: $('#expiry').val(),
                        cvc: $('#cvv').val(),
                        cardholder: $('#name').val()
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
                pay.done(function(data) {
                    if (data.DidValidate === false) {
                        ccAlert.html(data.ErrorMessage);
                        ccAlert.removeClass('hide');
                    } else if (data.DidValidate === true) {
                        console.log('didvalidate');
                        ccAlert.addClass('hide');
                        action.val('SendOrderVerify');
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });
                pay.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                });
            } else {
                ccform.addClass('hide');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any loop. Maybe you're not showing us the important part of the code.

Comment: Am I following your logic right: when the form is submitted -> do AJAX call -> if `data.DidValidate` -> submit form. Looks like an infinite loop to me. Maybe instead of doing this all on form submit you should do it on submit button click, then use `event.preventDefault()` so it only submits when you trigger it programmatically.

Comment: @Ionut, I just updated the code to include everything.

Comment: @dan08, you have the logic correct. I can easily submit the form with a click function. I was hoping to use a submit function, if possible, since its more intrinsic to the form submission process.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to attach event handlers from within an event handler. Instead, attach all event handlers in your initial load/document.ready callback. If you're bound and determined to use the submit event handler, you'll need to add a check to see if a particular flag is present (maybe if `action.val() === 'SendOrderVerify'`?) and continue the submission process rather than running the validation again.

Comment: I would change `cartForm.submit(function() {...})` to a click handler on the submit button. `submitButton.click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });` where ... is your existing callback logic.

Answer (score 0):

You want to skip the whole form validation and resubmission after you submit the form programmatically. You are already using an `action` variable that we can use to control the flow.
I'm going to try to abbreviate your code a bit for this example:

```
 // Post CC to Paymentvalidate
 cartForm.submit(function(e) {
 var form = $(this),
    action = $('#Action');

    if( action.val() != 'SendOrderVerify' ){//avoids the resubmit
        action.val('PAYMENTVALIDATE');            
        // Post Form if it validates
        if (form.parsley().isValid()) {
            var pay = //ajax call

            pay.done(function(data) {
              if (data.DidValidate === false) {
                ccAlert.html(data.ErrorMessage);
                ccAlert.removeClass('hide');
              } else if (data.DidValidate === true) {
                ccAlert.html(data.ErrorMessage).addClass('hide');
                action.val('SendOrderVerify');
                form.submit();
              }
            });

            pay.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            });
        }
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Since you change that `action.val()` value to indicate the action you are doing, we just use that in your submission logic. Now if `action.val()=='SendOrderVeify'` it will skip you extra verify steps (since they already ran) and in turn the `form.submit()` will not be run again. Therefore no submission loop.

Comment: form[0].submit() would have had the same result, only without calling the jquery event handler again. (assuming there's no `id="submit"` or `name="submit"` within the form.)

Comment: @dan08, I followed your example to bypass the validation/post if the form action is SendOrderVerify. I'm not sure why, but I'm still caught in a loop. I added the current code above.

Comment: Oh doy, the value gets reset. We need to move `action.val('PAYMENTVALIDATE');` in to the condition. Check my update

Comment: Thanks, @dan08. That does make sense. I did modify my code per your example. What's interesting is that we get all the way to the point where the action is set to SendOrderVerify(as seen in the success callback), but the form is not submitted.

Comment: Oh, its not in my trimmed down example, but `e.preventDefault()` should be in the if statement also, so it doesn't prevent the submission when it shouldn't.

Comment: When you say it "also" should be in the "if" statement, do you mean in addition to the existing e.preventDefault()? It sounds like you may be saying "instead of" the existing instance. Also, which if statement are you referring to? Finally, do you see any harm in moving the setting of the paymentvalidate action into the isValid() function since we don't need/want to set that action if the form isn't valid?

Comment: I mean "instead of". I was saying "also" in relation to the other statement we had to move into the if block. As for the paymentvalidate action. I think that's your call. I don't really see what your doing with it (other than if statement now).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've updated the code under the "Consolidated Update - Not Working" heading to do what I think you're suggesting. Can you please verify I'm not understanding incorrectly. It still doesn't submit for some reason. Thanks for your speedy responses.